# Jordan domains on sphere can be mapped to each other by homeomorphism isotopic to identity.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, curves

Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be a Jordan domains on $\mathbb{S}^2$. More formally, there exist two continuos injective maps $\phi$ and $\psi$ from $B = \{z \in \mathbb{C}||z| \leq 1\}$ to $\mathbb{S}^2$ and $D_1 = \phi(B),\, D_2 = \psi(B)$. I want to prove that there exists homeomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{S}^2$ such that $f(D_1) = D_2$ and $f$ is isotopic to identity.

My idea was to extend $\phi$ and $\psi$ to homeomorphisms $\hat{\phi}$ and $\hat{\psi}$ of $\mathbb{S}^2$, which are homotopic to each other, then use the result that any two homotopic homeomorphisms of a compact surface(unless this surface is closed annulus or closed disk) are actually isotopic. This theorem(Theorem 1.12, page 41) is stated in *A Primer on Mapping Class Groups by Benson Farb and Dan Margalit.*

To construct such nice extensions I was wondering to apply the Jordan-Schonflies theorem, which says that $\partial D_1$ and $\partial D_2$ nicely separate $\mathbb{S}^2$. For homotopy equivalence, I was thinking about using the fact that if a continuous map $h:\mathbb{S}^1 \to X$ extends to a continuous map $k: B \to X$ then $h$ is nullhomotopic(for example, see Lemma 55.3, page 349 from *Topology, Second Edition, by James R. Munkres*).

Unfortunately, I still not able to mix all the ideas in order to obtain complete proof.

P.S. Fact that for any two Jordan domains $X, Y$ of connected surface $M$ there exists homeomorphism of $M$ isotopic to identity and mapping $X$ to $Y$ is stated on page 422 in *Expanding Thurston Maps by Mario Bonk and Daniel Meyer*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3647, also here is an outline of a proof. Nevertheless, this proof sounds to me not complete enough, also I am particularly interested in the case of the 2-sphere and in completing my own arguments.

Comment: I do not have time to think about this now, but I think your statement would be a particular case of the canonical Jordan-Schoenflies theorem, saying that you can choose $f$ depending continuously on your curves $\partial D_1$ and $\partial D_2$. I learned about it in F. Le Roux's thesis (in French), but anyway, I think you should look for these key-words.

Comment: I found this paper which seems to do it in dimension $n$ : https://maths.dur.ac.uk/users/mark.a.powell/Gauld%20canonical%20Schoenflies.pdf

Comment: The existence of an extension is an easy consequence of Schoenflies. Isotopy to identity is hard.